# Retrieving data from property lists

Tags: swift, nsbundle

I have a plist data, contains an `array` of `dictionaries`, and I want to get all the dictionaries first value which's `english`

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"idictionary", ofType: "plist")
let plistData = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
print(plistData![0]) // only gets the first one
```

printing `print(plistData![0])` will only show this in the log

```
{
    english = abbey;
    kurdi = "\U06a9\U0644\U06ce\U0633\U06d5";
}
```

but I want to print all the `dictionaries` english value

here's a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JoZM.png) of my plist 
I have a bunch of records, and trying to get every item's `english` value

Comment: Unclear; could you show the actual input and desired output?

Comment: @matt, question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load your data the modern way (Swift 4): declare a struct:

```
struct Word : Decodable { let english:String; let kurdi:String }
```

Load the data into an array of that struct:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"idictionary", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
let array = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Word].self, from: data)
```

Now you have an array of Word, where every Word has an `english` property. If you want the english only, map the array:

```
let englishArray = array.map{$0.english}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to loop over the array

```
for item in plistData {
   print(item)
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you, your code worked, i am new to swift, don't really know if your way or @vadian's way are more efficient